# Append row and update value Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there code for Append rows to df2 and, when appended, change value of that row?

I want to append (or really cut) row/s which meet a few different criteria from df_Clean to df_VOIDS and then update the 'Drop_Reason' col to a new value; ie indicating the criteria it was moved.

df_Clean=

```
Encoder Index   Void    Phase Max   Force Max   Force Avg   THD Max 
       125545   NaN             0          54          19         6
       125583   NaN            12          79          54        16
```

df_VOIDS=

```
Encoder_Index   Void    Phase_Max   Force_Max   Force_Avg   THD_Max Drop_Reason
       125544   Void            5           59          39        14    Voided
       125657   Void            5           80          44        23    Voided
       125901   Void            6           80          43        19    Voided
       125963   Void            6           78          54        14    Voided
```

If Phase Max > 10, then ideally the last row of df_Clean would be removed and added to df_VOIDS with "above phase max" added to 'Drop_Reason'.

I'm doing several criteria checks ie Force Max, Force Avg etc in case that changes the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't use [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) any more as it is deprecated. Instead, use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html). There are a couple of optimisations you can make to your code, and you can resolve the worry about replacing all `NaN` values in the `Drop_Reason` column by adding the required value to the rows you transfer:

```py
Phase_Max_Value = 10
xfer = df_Clean.Phase_Max > Phase_Max_Value
df_VOIDS = pd.concat([df_VOIDS, df_Clean[xfer].assign(Drop_Reason='GrtrT Phase_Max')])
df_Clean = df_Clean[~xfer]
```

Resultant dataframes:

```
# df_VOIDS
   Encoder_Index  Void  Phase_Max  Force_Max  Force_Avg  THD_Max      Drop_Reason
0         125544  Void          5         59         39       14           Voided
1         125657  Void          5         80         44       23           Voided
2         125901  Void          6         80         43       19           Voided
3         125963  Void          6         78         54       14           Voided
1         125583   NaN         12         79         54       16  GrtrT Phase_Max
# df_Clean
   Encoder_Index  Void  Phase_Max  Force_Max  Force_Avg  THD_Max
0         125545   NaN          0         54         19        6
```

Comment: Nice, thanks Nick. I had figured there had to be something more solid. Did you assign the variable 'xfer' because you used it twice?

Comment: @Nick_Jo yes, as that avoids possible mis-typing errors when using it the second time,  and the fact that it makes the code cleaner, especially if `xfer` takes on a more complicated function

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting my current answer but definitely welcome other suggestions.

Here's working code one of several criteria:

```
Phase_Max_Value = 10
df_VOIDS = df_VOIDS.append(df_Clean[df_Clean.Phase_Max > Phase_Max_Value])

#if Drop_Reason equals NaN than Drop reason = 'Phase Max'
df_VOIDS.loc[df_VOIDS['Drop_Reason'].isna(),'Drop_Reason']='GrtrT Phase_Max'
df_Clean = df_Clean[df_Clean.Phase_Max <= Phase_Max]
```

Once the Appended row comes across it fills Drop_Reason with NaN. Then I replace all NaN's in the column with a reason, but it feels a little dangerous blindly overwriting NaN's. This gives:

df_Clean=

```
Encoder Index   Void    Phase Max   Force Max   Force Avg   THD Max 
       125545   NaN             0          54          19         6
```

df_VOIDS =

```
Encoder_Index   Void    Phase_Max   Force_Max   Force_Avg   THD_Max Drop_Reason
125544          Void            5          59          39        14      Voided
125657          Void            5          80          44        23      Voided
125901          Void            6          80          43        19      Voided
125963          Void            6          78          54        14      Voided
125583           NaN            12         79          54        16  GrtrT Phase_Max
```

Thanks for your time.